# Kendo MVC Grid Multiple Column Filters

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am unable to get my grid to filter on more than 1 column. When I try to add the 2nd filter I get a 500 error. It never hits my controller POST action. I'm getting this behavior on 2 different grid and datasources.

Grid (shortened example):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<FooItemViewModel>()
.Name("FooGrid")
.Columns(column =>
{
    column.Bound(p => p.FooTypeCode).Title("Type").Width(22);
    column.Bound(p => p.FooCode).Title("Foo Code").Width(40);
    column.Bound(p => p.FooDesc).Title("Foo Description").Width(260);
    column.Bound(p => p.ReportCode).Title("Report").Width(20);
})
.Filterable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable(builder => builder.PageSizes(new[] { 10, 25, 100 }))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(25)
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(s => s.FooID);
        m.Field(s => s.FooID).Editable(false);
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Foo"))  // kendo adds its datasourcerequest on first 2 calls (empty & filter 1)
    .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Foo"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Foo"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "Foo"))
    .Events(events => events.Error("onDataSourceError"))
))
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var Foos = _db.Foos.Project().To<FooItemViewModel>();
    DataSourceResult response = Foos.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When the grid first loads I hit the Read action with empty datasourcerequest as expected. When I add a filter I also hit the server read action with a datasourcerequest and the expected column filter passed in. When I select a 2nd column filter and click "Filter" I get the 500 error even though it looks like a very similar request:

Actually when I look at the 2 POSTs they are similar:

> Working request: 
>   sort=&page=1&pageSize=25&group=&filter=FooCode~contains~'10.1'
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:61556/Foo/Read
>
> Request Method: POST Status Code: 200 OK Remote Address: [::1]:61556
>   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> Failing request: sort=&page=1&pageSize=25&group=&filter=FooCode~contains~'10.1'~and~FooDesc~contains~'hunt'
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:61556/Foo/Read Request Method: POST
>   Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error Remote Address: [::1]:61556
>   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in the 2017.3 release. Updating from 2017.3.1018 to 2017.3.1026 resolved the issue. See here: https://www.telerik.com/forums/asp-net-mvc-grid-multiple-column-filters#x0VfO3YHlkebR81muGeXbg

Comment: I have kendo version 2015.3.1111 , do i need to upgrade the version or my current version has the multiple column filtering?

Comment: @SanaT. Not sure when that feature was added, but if it is not working you will need to get to at least 2017.3